# How to update value of single field of same node using node_save?

Tags: 7, nodes, database, ajax

**The problem statement:**

I have one content type called 'Employee' which has 10 nodes.  I have to perform the voting for each node. I am saving the vote count in the field called 'vote count'.

But when I met the below scenario I have an issue of updating vote count for a single employee.

**Scenario**:
20 people voting for one employee at a time. This means the node will save the 20 times for updating the vote count. This may lead to race_condition while saving the node. But vote count is not updating correctly. This m=is due to race_condition?

I am using the `lock_aquire()` and `lock_release()` in below code.

is it right way to use this two functions while saving same node multiple times?
or
any other way to update the count?

**I have tried below attempt so far:**

1. added ajax call back in js

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/vote',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"nid": nid},
         success: function(response){}
});
```

2. menu hook with path :

`/ajax/vote`

3. A page call back function `general_voting_update_vote` to save the node;

```
function general_voting_update_vote() {
          $lock_name = 'register_vote';
          $nodeId = !empty($_POST['nid']) ? $_POST['nid'] : '';
          $node = node_load($nodeId);
          $vote = $node->field_vote_count_submitted[$node->language][0]['value'] + 1;
          $node->field_vote_count_submitted[$node->language][0]['value'] = $vote;
          $lock_acquired = lock_acquire($lock_name, 5.0);
          if (!empty($lock_acquired)) { 
            node_save($node);
          }
          lock_release($lock_name);
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider taking a different approach - like for example saving the individual votes somewhere separate when they happen (database, file system, whatever), then having a scheduled job to update the node based on that separate storage. That way you avoid the race condition, not to mention the large number of more expensive node save ops you will avoid

Comment: is it good to use  lock_aquire() and lock_release() ?